# How can i find the data i need in a record?

Tags: c, file, struct, fread

I'm writing a project in c. Everything seems to work just fine but one function. This function allows the user of the program to edit a registered record by searching its ID(which is an integer part of a struct as in struct generalPatient{...int id;...}): so, the user inserts the Id and if there's a correspondence in the read file the user can start inserting the new data.
Here's the important part of the code i've written:

```
FILE *writePatient = fopen("data.dat", "rb+");
if (writePatient == NULL) {

    fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
    exit(1);
}
else {
    puts("Insert account Id you need to edit.");
    int editId;
    scanf("%d", &editId);

    int fnd = 0;
    int elsw, chsz = sizeof(struct generalPatient);
    while (fread(&patient, chsz, 1, writePatient))
    {
        if (editId == patient.id){
 do stuff
}
```

The rest of the code is not important because the "if" won't verify the condition and no matter how many IDs i try, it never finds a correspondence. So, the error must be in these lines. Can anybody find the problems in these few lines of codes or at least suggest me where could the problem be? I've written an identical function to allow user to edit data of another struct and it works. I really have no idea how to fix this.
EDIT:
I write on the patient file using "a" mode, so that it should always add a new record on the end of the file. The id is inserted automatically like this:

```
srand(time(NULL));
patient.id=1 + rand()%9999;
```

and the writing is done like this, after letting he user insert all the required data:

```
fwrite (&patient, sizeof(struct generalPatient), 1, writePatient);
```

To add further information, I've written a function that lets the user search for a specific patient using the patient's id and it works fine:

```
   readPatientPointer = fopen ("data.dat", "r");//apertura file
if (readPatientPointer == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
    exit (1);
}else{
    int check=0;
    puts("Insert ID of the patient you're looking for.\nInsert a char to exit the program.");
    int searchId;
    if(scanf("%d", &searchId)!=1){
        puts("bye.");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    while(fread(&patientRead, sizeof(struct generalPatient), 1, readPatientPointer)){
            if(searchId==patientRead.id){
  do stuff}
```

Comment: It will be difficult to suggest a fix without seeing the code that writes the file. I suggest you create 3 test categories: (a) read from an empty file, (b) read from a file with one patient, (c) read from a file with two patients. For b and c, test what happens when you look for something that should be there and then for something that should not be there. When searching for something that should be there, look for the first one and then again for the last one.

Comment: we need to see how you wrote the file

Comment: Hello guys, I've edited my post adding info about how i write on the patient file and showing another function (a working one) that makes me search for the patient using the id. Hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out. I simply had to change rb+ in r+. That is super weird because other functions that were written and linked with other functions in the same identical way were working but oh well, black magic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).